# How do I use different threads for different tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

Here's what I tried.
Basically a Banner which displays a *scrolling text and a flashing image*. I get no output but something seems to be running in the processes.
My problem statement says create a Banner using Applet and Multithreading where each thread is doing a different task.
Eg: One thread is displaying a scrolling banner while other is playing music, etc.

---

```
class Text extends Applet implements Runnable {
    String msg = " Marvel Electronics ";
    boolean stopFlag;
    Thread t1 = null;   
    public void init() {
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    public void start() {
        t1 = new Thread(this);
        stopFlag=false;
        t1.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        char c;
        for(;;) {
            try {
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(300);
                c = msg.charAt(0);
                msg=msg.substring(1, msg.length());
                msg+=c;
                if(stopFlag)
                    break;
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
    public void stop() {
        stopFlag=true;
        t1 = null;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString(msg, 20, 30);
        showStatus("Banner");
    }
}
class Image extends Applet implements Runnable {
    Thread t2 = null;
    public void start() {
        t2 = new Thread(this);
        t2.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        for(;;) {
            try {
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics gfx) {
        gfx.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        gfx.fillRect(20, 50, 50, 50);
        gfx.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        gfx.fillOval(25, 55, 30, 30);
        gfx.drawString("ME", 35, 65);
    }
    public void stop() {
        t2 = null;
    }
}
public class Banner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Text t = new Text();
        Image i = new Image();
        t.start();
        i.start();
    }
}
```

There is no output on the screen but eclipse shows a process running. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Applets are obsolete / out-dated / [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html). Why are you writing applets?

Comment: To run a class implementing runnable you should Instantiate a Thread class and then give the instance of your Text class as an argument.Otherwise the method run will never be called

Comment: You aren't calling any method to display your applets, as far as I can see.

Comment: I'm a beginner. Could someone elaborate.

Comment: @RyanDsilva don't bother learning applets. You can re-write your classes to extend `Component` instead with very little extra work. Proceed according to Sergei Sirik's answer below, it also works for `Component`s (since `Applet` also extends `Component`).

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your applets incorrectly. You have to execute it via applet tag from html or from some awt swing Container. Check this: http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/getStarted/applet/index.html

You can start with this:

```
public class Banner {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 300);

        Text t = new Text();
        Image i = new Image();
        t.start();
        i.start();

        frame.getContentPane().add(t);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        i.init();
        i.start();
        t.init();
        t.start();
    }
}
```

it will show you JFrame with background color and running text:

[image: result]

Comment: Agreed. I was able to do this. But when it comes to using two threads for two different tasks and display them on the same screen i cant seem to do it.

Comment: There should be a `frame.getContentPane().add(i);` in the code to add the second applet.